# Using multiple classes together as a hash key

Tags: ruby, data-structures, ruby-hash

I found a script that calculates 3D models and combines identical vertices. It has the following logic, where according to my understanding, vertices are hash maps of vertex class:

```
unless vertices.key?(vertex)
  new_vertices << vertex
  vertices[ vertex ] = @vertex_index
  @vertex_index += 1
end
```

If we find a `vertex` that is unique, we add it to the `new_vertices` array.

I'd like to modify this so that the key for the hash map is a combination of a vertex and a material (both are classes from Sketchup, which is the software this script runs in). What is the best way to do this so that each key is a combination of two classes instead of one? Some sort of duple or class holding both the vertex and the material? Is that supported by a hash map?

Comment: Use an array `[vertex, material]` as a key.

Comment: *"Is that supported by a hash map?"* -- Yes. In ruby, you can use **any object** (including, for example, an `Array`) as a hash key. Unlike some other languages, with may only allow `String`s and `Integer`s as hash keys.

Comment: Thanks guys. Never used a languages with this sort of flexibility before. In terms of code, would it literally just support using what @mudasobwa wrote in place of the vertex for the key? If so, that's awesome and if you answer it, I'll give you credit for the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby one might use whatever as hash key:

```
hash = {
  42 => "an integer",
  [42, "forty two"] => "an array",
  Class => "a class"
}
#⇒  {42=>"an integer", [42, "forty two"]=>"an array", Class=>"a class"}

hash[[42, "forty two"]]
#⇒ "an array"
```

That said, in your case you might use an array `[vertex, material]` as a key:

```
unless vertices.key?([vertex, material])
  new_vertices_and_materials << [vertex, material]
  vertices[[vertex, material]] = @vertex_index
  @vertex_index += 1
end
```

---

The more rubyish approach would be to call [`Enumerable#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq) on the input and do:

```
input = [ # example input data
  [:vertex1, :material1],
  [:vertex2, :material1],
  [:vertex2, :material1],
  [:vertex2, :material2],
  [:vertex2, :material2]
]
new_vertices_and_materials = input.uniq
vertices_and_materials_with_index =
  new_vertices_and_materials.
    zip(1..new_vertices_and_materials.size).
    to_h
#⇒ {[:vertex1, :material1]=>1,
#   [:vertex2, :material1]=>2,
#   [:vertex2, :material2]=>3}
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking that down for me. Very helpful!